# Mark attribute to ignore in Orange

Tags: python, orange

Using Orange3 library within my Python code.

I am trying to mark a given feature as ignore (or i), so that feature will not be imported.

Like the flags discussed on this link

https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.io.html#single-line-header-format

I am trying to do it within the python script.

```
ignore_var_name = "i#"+dv.name
ignore_dv = DiscreteVariable(name=ignore_var_name, values=dv.values)
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Cannot find any examples which show how can one do it within the script.

Wondering if someone can point me to how to go about marking an attribute as to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore mark (#i) is for labeling headers in the file and is used only in parsing of the file.

But once you have the data object, you need to change its domain. Like this:

```
data = Orange.data.Table('iris')
attributes = [attr for attr in data.domain.attributes if attr.name != 'petal length']
new_domain = Orange.data.Domain(attributes, data.domain.class_vars, data.domain.metas)
new_data = data.transform(new_domain)
```

You could also move the unwanted feature into data.domain.metas with a similar procedure as above.